# Joomla main page header length maxmizing

Tags: joomla-3.x

Unable to adjust main page header length of the  Joomla karoltheme template(v 3.9.1). Tried changing the template.jss but failed. Great to know the correct way of adjusting the main page header length.

Below is the current and expected format. As you can see in "As-is" Downloads menu is appearing in the bottom which suppose to be next to "Contact us" in same line.

As is:

[image]

To be :

[image]

template.css
[image]

Comment: We will need to see the attempts that you have written in your `template.jss` file (this will clarify if you have attempted a css or js solution -- because `.jss` files don't exist as far as I know)  How does your site look on mobile?  Are we able to have a link to your site so that we can see it for ourselves and perhaps check the generated source code?

Comment: thank you @mickmackusa .. Is it possible can i ping you in skype only for some info which i cant paste here..

Comment: Sorry, not only is now "family time", it is unfair for me to be exposed to private details while other volunteers are not.  If you have sensitive data, you may obfuscate/redact it in any way you like.  I hope you can manage to offer some more details without compromising your security/privacy.

Comment: I tried searching for the Karoltheme, and variations of its name, but couldn't find anything like a template for Joomla. Could you paste a link to where you got the template from?  Your issues also looks like it is more of a Header width issue rather than length so checking your template to see if you can adjust the page or module width would be a good start or try and reduce the space between menu items to squeeze in a few more characters to fit Download.

Comment: @mickmackusa Is this helpful ?

Comment: It is better than nothing, but providing code as a screenshot is the least valuable way to present it. 
1. Volunteers may have to squint, or click and zoom in to see the content. 2. Volunteers can't copy-paste your work into their local environment to replicate the problem.  3. Some of your lines in the file may get cut off in the screenshot, but we may need to see the whole thing. 4. Search engines can't pick up the content (and this is critical for the health of this network).

Comment: I don't have this template at my disposal, perhaps you could also paste (into your question) the html mark up for that specific portion of the template.